# Why am I unable to remove element using directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I can't figure-out why my directive is failing.

```
app.directive('errSrc', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('error', function() {
                element.remove();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This directive fails to remove the elements to which it applies. However, if I replace the:

```
element.remove();
```

with:

```
element.hide();
```

it will hide the element.

As far as I understand from the angular documentation both .remove() and .hide() methods are part of the JQLite that's baked-into angular so they should both work.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `scope.$apply();` after `element.remove();`?

Comment: I have, it doesn't seem to change anything -_-

Comment: May be you are trying to remove element when they are added, ie in the 'same time'. Try some async stuff? ($timeout)

Comment: Could be...but then why would scope.hide() work? Wouldn't it be trying to hide things that don't exist too?

I'll try that though, weirder things have worked before ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the 'error' event you are trying to bind to is.

But when I tried binding to a click event, it works just fine.

```
myApp.directive('rmv', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() { 
                element.remove()
            });
        }
    }
});

<div rmv>Remove me!</div>
```

Comment: I'm adding this directive to an array of images from an API. Some of these images either 404 or have malformed URLs and therefore don't load; the purpose of this directive is to remove those images. It hides them correctly when I use element.hide() but not element.remove() for some reason...

Comment: I just tried it with images and incorrect urls. It works just fine for me. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JoeSham/wp4d9fv1/10/